# How to display DecalGeometry from ThreeJs on Specific Mesh

Tags: javascript, threejs-editor, decal

I have this Mesh:
[The specific mesh named **OCounter**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwyP.png)
and I want to display the Decal on the front of the mesh.

I tried this:

```
    textureDecal.side = THREE.DoubleSide
  const euler = new THREE.Euler(0,0,0, "XYZ");
  const decalImage = new DecalGeometry(
    OCounter,
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5),
    euler,
    new THREE.Vector3(2,2, 10)
  );

  
  const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    transparent: true, 
    depthTest: true,   
    depthWrite: false,   
    polygonOffset: true,  
    polygonOffsetFactor: -4,   
    
  });


  decalMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  DecalLogo = new THREE.Mesh(decalImage, decalMaterial);
  scene.add(DecalLogo);
```

I tried with a cube and a sphere, it works properly by changing **Vector3** values in **DecalGeometry**.

But even with various settings on this mesh, it does not display at all, not even a small portion of the decal.